Updating MSO 2016 PRO Plus to MSO 2019 PRO Plus
Can I update Office 2016 PRO Plus to Office 2019 PRO Plus without losing any settings or email/folders? I have 2016 MSO Version 2404 Build 16.0.17531.20152.  When I clicked on UPDATE OPTIONS and
Update Now, I wasn't sure what I was going to be updated to.  I don't want OFFICE 365, just Office 2019 PRO Plus.  I have also read that updates for 2016 can include 2019 features.  Based on my
version, do I NEED to update to 2019.  Same questions apply to MSO 2021 PRO Plus, should I decide to go that route.

“I have also read that updates for 2016 can include 2019 features” - This is false. This is the difference between the perpetual license of (Office 2016 and Office 2019) and Office 365. The perpetual licenses feature set are locked they only receive security updates. The only way Office 2016 or Office 2019 will get updated features is if you log into a MSA that is subscribed to Office 365, doing so will as a by product of the subscription, upgrade the install to the current Office 365 build. Office will tell you which update it will install. Yes; You can uninstall 2016 and upgrade to 2019
